# How to transfer photos from OS X Tiger to iPad iOS 7

Tags: ipad, photos.app, migration, macos

My mom got an iPad Air as a birthday present. She has been using an iBook G4 running 10.4.11 until now.

I am trying to migrate her photos from the iBook (iPhoto) to the iPad. Is there any easy  way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No easy way no.

G4 with 10.4 means a (very) old iTunes version (9.2.1). For iTunes 10 you need a least Leopard.

To sync with iOS7 (the default OS of the iPad Air) you'll need iTunes 11.1.

Other options :

- Use a another (more recent) mac to do it
- send the images with an app or mail (veeeeeery long)

Comment: yeah these would be the insane ways I guess haha.
Using the "another Mac" option, would you go about this by installing recent iPhoto on this Mac, then import the old iPhoto lib into it? 


then use iTunes to move the images to the iPad?

Sorry if these are silly questions, I'm a dev and would be most happy with a CLI solution.

Comment: Yeah CLI would be great but there is no one that I know of. The easiest way is probably using the photostream. Here is an example from Windows if that's an option : http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/apple/3444903/transfer-photos-from-computer-iphone/

Comment: ok I'm exporting all photos from the old iPhoto to a folder on my Mac via Wifi. Will then sync this folder to the iPad via iTunes, no need for iPhoto (1 GB download!) for this then.

Comment: ok got it. it was even more insane than i feared it to be: during the syncing process, itunes kept adding data to a folder "ipod thumbnail cache" or something, which  incrementally doubled the size of the photo lib in question. this filled up my SDD, which resulted in itunes cancelling the transfer (without any error message, it just stopped syncing). so this involved a fun session of deleting caches, bloated apps etc. form my Mac.... i rate the overall migration process D-, not fun at all. Mom would never have been able to do it herself.

Answer (score 1):

If I plug my iphone 5s into our old Sony Vio (2003) it sees all the photos as if the phone was a camera. We have a G5 Powermac and a much newer MacBook Pro. Neither will allow me to get photos from the iphone. The only draw back is the photos are number img001 etc. Once brought back to the Mac though, the Metadata is intact. 
I always thought Apple was a great platform. they invented "plug and play" but the simple task of getting photos off a phone , via USB (which has been around for years) seems to much to ask.
To solve the nice file names that the iphone issues (based on date and time, I am writing a script (in Applescript) to apply the date and time data to the file name. (have to change . to : and . to - for date and time thought)